# How to retrieve values from Enums stored in a map?

Tags: java, enums, constants, maps

How to get values out of enums stored in a map?

I have multiple enum types in a class. These enum types are stored as values in a map. My requirement is to get values from a particular enum type (name passed as a parameter).

In the following example, Test1 and Test2 are stored in a map. I want to get corresponding values of Y for passed values of x and the enum type (Test1 and Test2..).

```
public class TestClass {
    public enum Test1 {
        Const1("x1", "y1"),
        Const2("x2", "y2");
        private String x;
        private String y;

        Test1(String x, String y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public enum Test2 {
        Const1("x1", "y1"),
        Const2("x2", "y2");
        private String x;
        private String y;

        Test2(String x, String y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static final Map<String, Collection<? extends Enum<?>>> testMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            new HashMap<String, Collection<? extends Enum<?>>>() {
                {
                    put("Test1", Arrays.asList(Test1.values()));
                    put("Test2", Arrays.asList(Test2.values()));
                }
            }
    );

    //get function to be called from outside 

    public static String getValueY(String x, String enumType) {
        return testMap.get(enumType).stream()....
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        getValueY("x1", "Test1"); //This should give value as y1
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem. If you want to get to fields belonging to an enum, you need to add getter methods, like `String getX()`, same for Y. And then, when iterating a list of enums, you just call the getter method, and depending on the results, you do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that I forgot to add here. But how would I get which enum I need to get this value X from? I will have name of the enum though during runtime, say Test1.

Comment: You have a map that maps "Test1" to the list of enum constants. You then check whether the enum constant getX() returns the one you are looking for? Still not sure what you are asking for or you are struggling with.

Comment: Actually I am unable to get this getX() function from the values that are returned from map for Test1. I don't want to use reflection. Any easy way?

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type-safe way to do this, without reflection:

Declare an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  String getX();
  String getY();
```

Have **all** your enums implement that interface:

```
public enum Test1 implements Foo { ...
```

Now you can change your map to

```
Map<String, Collection<Foo>> testMap
```

which then allows you to call both methods, `getX()` and `getY()`.